# Winforms ComboBox 2 way databinding only works 1 way

Tags: winforms, data-binding

I have a combobox, and in the design view I have it databound to a bindingsource as follows:

```
this.itemTypeComboBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", this.itemTypeContainerBindingSource, "ItemType", true));
this.itemTypeComboBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.itemTypeContainerBindingSource, "ItemType", true));
```

In the code behind in the load event I have the following:

```
// bind the combobox to the enum
this.itemTypeComboBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(OpticalItemType));

// bind a custom object to the datasource
this.itemTypeContainerBindingSource.DataSource = customObjectContainer;
```

The "customObjectContainer" is a single object that contains a property "ItemType" that is bound to the combobox, and all properties of the object use change notification through "INotifyPropertyChanged".

In my code behind, if I programmatically change the custom object, the changes are reflected in the combobox. However, if I change the combobox through the UI, the bindingsource, and hence the custom object do not reflect the changes.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

As it is a singular object, it cannot be to do with using BindingList etc.

### UPDATE 1:

Ok, whenever I change the combobox through the UI, it never changes the underlying object, the setter is never hit for the property in the custom object. However, I have just noticed that if I tab off of the control, it then fires the setter, and changes the underlying object. Why would this be?

### PROBLEM SOLVED:

It appears, the issue was with my binding. I added "DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged" to the bindings, and it works now!!

Comment: What's the type of "ItemType"? Maybe when the selected value in the combobox changes it tries to assign a string to a enum or vise versa.

Comment: "ItemType" is an enum instance of "OpticalItemType"

Comment: And it has a public setter?

Comment: Yep, it has a public getter and setter

Comment: Came across something, question updated

Comment: problem solved, the issue was with my binding, I added a binding mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with my binding. I added "DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged" to the bindings, and it works now!!