# Is it possible to use a EF navigation property as displaymember?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, listbox

I have an entity `Employee` which consists of an `EmployeeID` and `Job`.  I have another entity `Personel` which has `ID` and `Name`.  `EmployeeID` is a foreign key which is `ID` from the `Personel` entity.

In my code, I can do this:
`string nameStr = Employee.Personel.Name` using the navigation property of the `Employee` entity.

I'm trying to display the employees in a listbox.  What I can't do (or I don't know how to do) is use the nav property as the display member of the listbox so I get a nice name string rather than a persons ID.

I've tried this, and it didn't work:

```
myListbox.Datasource = Employee.ToList();
myListbox.DisplayMember = "Personel.Name";
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible?  That is use a navigation property the DisplayMember of a control (a listbox in this case)?

Cheers!

Comment: For the record, this works in WPF using `DisplayMemberPath="Personel.Name"`, but I guess you're using winforms, which is an obsolete technology that has all sorts of limitations and does not properly support databinding, and hence forces you into all sorts of horrible hacks for everything (such as creating anonymous classes and whatnot). I suggest you leave winforms behind and use proper UI technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can project your `Employee` class to an anonymous type and pass that into the control

```
var employees = EmployeeList.Select(e => new{e.Id, Name = e.Personel.Name});

myListbox.Datasource = employees;
myListbox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Comment: Thanks DDiVita.  Is there a way I can do this, and still implement two way databinding, so changes I make will be reflected in `Employee`?

Comment: @Yabbie, maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652968/winforms-combobox-2-way-databinding-only-works-1-way) would dhelp